# Can't connect to MySQL while building docker-compose image

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a configuration of docker-compose, and on building database step, django management throws an error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")

I think - the docker refusing connections.

Configuration by socket similar not working (Says `error connection by socket`)

**Docker Compose file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:5.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "bh"
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
    ports:
      - "3302:3306"


  behealthy_dev:
    build: .
    container_name: behealthy_dev
    expose:
      - "86"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - /behealthy_dev/
    ports:
      - "86:86"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /behealthy_dev
WORKDIR /behealthy_dev
ADD requirements.txt /behealthy_dev/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /behealthy_dev/
RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

**Database settings (settings)**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'bh',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
            'init_command': 'SET innodb_strict_mode=1',
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },

    },
}
```

Have any solutions? I tried to resolve from other stack answer but it's not working for me.

Comment: @sadok-f's answer is important (your database is not on `127.0.0.1`), but also you intrinsically cannot run database migrations from a Dockerfile; it does not have the Compose network environment, and it won't get rebuilt if you delete and recreate the database.

Answer (score 2):

in your service `behealthy_dev` change the MySQL host from

```
'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
```

to

```
'HOST': 'db',
```

Edit:
Change also the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"` to:

```
`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpassword"`
```

and your Database settings to:

```
'PASSWORD': 'rootpassword',
```

Comment: how should this work without networks settings in docker-compose ?

Comment: if no network settings were specified, docker composer will create a network with the default driver.

Comment: updated my  answer, try to change to `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD `